Heuristic for "optimising" assets in a min/worst of basket option
Given a universe of X stocks, I'm trying to find what combination of 3 would result in the highest premium for a 'Worst Of Put'
$$
max(1-min(\frac {S(T)_1} {K_1},...,\frac {S(T)_i} {K_i}),0)
$$
I guess I don't really need full optimisation, as I'm not looking for accurate premiums, I just was wondering if there is any heuristic or quick calcs I could use to infer which combinations would likely rank highest. I have access to a Bloomberg Terminal.
I've copied some people's python scripts and monte carlo's to try and do this, but I hate the feeling of not really the why/how of certain sections of the code.
Conscious that the answer may be "this is complex for a reason and can't be simplified" but I thought I should still ask. Regardless thanks for the help.
Some context: I work in exotic / structured product sales at a distributor / wholesaler. In my team I'm treated as the 'quant' but comparatively to the traders/structures at the banks I'm very behind. While I'm striving to be able to solve this problem myself, it comes up very frequently, and I'm not quite at the stage.
As I'm sure many structurers/traders in here would understand - investors in yield enhanced structured products love to increase their premium by selling a 'worst of put option' so I'm trying to find a way to help them do that. I know there's many groups out there offering these tools, but we don't have a lot of budget.

What assumptions do you want to use to calculate it? You mention a Monte Carlo, so do you assume some probability distributions? Or do you want to price it according to market data and just optimize to find the highest pair of three given the market data?

@MrLCh Its a good question. I think my gut feel is just utilising the market data.
I was trying to think of a good way to articulate my question, because I don't think it's purely about optimization.
I think the actual question may be regarding the correlation risk itself. I.e if we assume a 3 stock basket(A,B,C) stock C had 0.7 correlation to A/B and ~24 volatility. My question is kind of "How can I target substitutes for stock C?" because perhaps I can take more correlation risk with lower volatility

I think to get give a reasonable answer you really need to set a framework and assumptions. Do you assume that you know the correlations between returns, do you want to calculate the implied correlations from a set of derivatives if available? Or is your question more a question of just interest and you want to build intuition with regards to the behavior of the options?

Regarding Bloomberg, do you have access to DLIB and the derivatives API (DTK)? There is a XLTP, that allows you to do this if you can price deals in excel. That said, it's very computationally intensive and the number of stocks is limited.
